# Объясните, как сортируется этот список в Python

Tags: python, сортировка, list

*решил порешать задачки с инета, да бы закрепить знания, прежде чем перейти к след главе читаемой книги*

И наткнулся где-то в комментах на такой код

```
l = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (100, 1)]
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[::-1]))
```

изучил параметр key, изучил досконально саму функцию sorted, так же знаю про срезы и lambda, т.е знаю все что есть в этом коде. Вроде как понимаю, что он сортирует их по второму элементу(это и является для меня проблемой, так как не понимаю, как он получает инфу про 2 элемент), НО

```
lambda x: x[::-1]
```

просто возвращает перевернутый список, как это помогает функции `sorted()`отсортировать список по второму элементу из кортежа, как она получает его значение

такой код я понимаю

```
a = ['abc','a','ab']
print(sorted(a, key = len))
```

он берет длину строк и использует их для сортировки, а дальше `sorted()` по своей специфики сортирует от меньшего к больше, А ТО НЕТ !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
HELP!!!!!!!!!!!!!
желательно подробно и разжеванной =3

Answer (score 5):

Все достаточно просто - в ключе сортировки используется лямбда функция, которая возвращает кортеж перевернутый задом-наперёд. Т.е. из `(1, 2)` получается `(2, 1)`, `(4, 5)` -> `(5, 4)`, `(100, 1)` -> `(1, 100)`.

```
In [162]: [x[::-1] for x in l]
Out[162]: [(2, 1), (5, 4), (1, 100)]
```

Answer (score 4):

все просто

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

стоит задача - надо отсортировать список кортежей по возрастанию второго элемента в кортеже

по умолчанию питон сортирует от первого элемента кортежа к последнему, но нам требуется наоборот, поэтому мы разворачиваем кортежи и дальше питон сортирует как обычно

т.е.

```
[(1, 2), (4, 5), (100, 1)]
```

превращаем в

```
[(2, 1), (5, 4), (1, 100)]
```

что при сортировке даст

```
[(1, 100), (2, 1), (5, 4)]
```

Но поскольку сортируется именно наш список, то получаем

```
[(100, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
```

С тем же успехом можно было бы написать:

```
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[-1]))
```

и получить такой же результат - т.е. сортируем строго по последнему элементу кортежа из списка, но тогда для списков с одинаковым первым параметром случилась бы проблема:

```
l = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (100, 1), (99, 1)]
```

дал бы

```
[(100, 1), (99, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
```

а не

```
[(99, 1), (100, 1), (1, 2), (4, 5)]
```

а при переворачивании кортежей получаем сортировку не по одному элементу, а по всем элементам кортежа (т.е. когда первые элементы двух кортежей одинаковы, то смотрим вторые элементы и уже на основании их решаем какой кортеж левее, а какой правее)

**P.S.**

к сожалению в python3 нет нормальной сортировки, которую можно задать через функцию сравнения двух объектов, например

```
sorted(arr, lambda obj1, obj2: obj1 < obj2)
```

поэтому приходится извращаться

Например, если бы было требование отсортировать список кортежей так, чтобы второй элемент возрастал, а первый убывал, то пришлось бы написать вот такой код:

```
l = [(1, 2), (4, 5), (100, 1), (99, 1)]
print(sorted(l, key=lambda x: (x[1], -x[0])))
```

Comment: RoflanEbalo, СПС понял ^_^ .

Comment: т.е в lambda передаются элементы списка, а не сам список, как было бы с  for i in l ? есть разъяснение  - почему?

Comment: да, именно так - типа питон дает стандартный алгоритм сортировки, а уж ты ломай голову чтобы преобразовать свой элемент в пригодный для нормальной сортировки вид :) 
вроде объясняют тем, что большинство задач можно решить именно таким способом, а кто не верит - тот дурак :)

Comment: В Python 3 есть такая сортировка: [cmp_to_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key). `sorted(arr, key=cmp_to_key(lambda obj1, obj2: obj1 < obj2))`.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, не знал - везде было написано, что сортировку в таком виде выпилили из 2 питона

Comment: Сортировку выпилили, это правда. Гвидо счастлив. Функцию добавили. Программисты довольны. Константа стала хуже из-за создания объектов, но на фоне интерпретатора не заметно.